# IEEE format caption alignment

Tags: captions, ieeetran

When I put a caption on the figures, the alignment changes to Left !
why this happens and how to fix it ?

I recently removed the `caption` package to cope with change that occures in caption font size
but the problem is now : correct font size but Left (instead of center) alignment.
ieee

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.45 \textwidth]{final.jpg}
    \caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Left alignment of captions is an explicit design choice of the IEEE class. Don't change it if you plan to submit to an IEEE publication. If you are not doing that don't use a journal specific class file:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Using the `conference` option you get centered captions. Removing it you get left aligned captions.

Comment: The question is not clear for me. Do you want centered or left-aligned captions? The former is the default with `conference`, the latter the default without it.

Comment: I'm writing a conference paper with [conference] enabled, as in the text above, but the alignment is left
I think it should be centered for IEEE conference papers

Comment: In fact. You should have something else in your document that changes this behavior. Please try to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @karlkoeller yes (well I knew it changed depending on the options) The main point is though that you should not adjust the caption formatting of a conference or journal class)

Comment: As the working example shows, no extra option is enabled.
The figure's caption should be center alignd, I double checked.
Current alignment is Left.
A working example attached

Comment: I get centered captions. Try updating your packages.

Comment: Thanks, It was due to the 1.8 version fault. Version 1.8a solved the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to an outdated package, solved by updating.